# I am deploying a simple spring boot app bu it is showing this error

Tags: spring-boot, heroku, websocket

I don't have any idea about this, I have also tried to change its version to 11 but it doesn't works

```
       [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Total time:  14.098 s
       [INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-31T17:21:13Z
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project chatroom: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 16 -> [Help 1]
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
       [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
       [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
 !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
       We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
       please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
 !     Push failed
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out first paragraph in [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-fix-invalid-target-release-17-18-19-or-110)

Comment: You configured your build for java 16, but the available JDK is < 16. Either install JDK 16 or higher, or set the java version to al ower one.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the installed version of jdk is 16 (or above) and check your project in your development environment if its configured for this version too.

**invalid target release: 16**

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.